# Separar 3 select en un Form

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema con 3 select y un label dentro de mi formulario, no encunetro la forma de separarlos para darles las posiciones correctas

Código html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Imagenes/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/Registros.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/Regiones.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Registro - Adopción</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="FormTitulo">Registro de Adopción</h1>
    <form action="" class="Registro">
        <h2 class="FormSubtitulo">CREA UNA NUEVA CUENTA</h2>
        <div class="Contenedor-Registro">
            <input type="email" name="TxtCorreo" placeholder="Correo Electronico" id="TxtCorreo" class="input-100">
            <input type="text" name="TxtNombres" placeholder="Nombre Completo" id="TxtNombres" class="input-100">
            <input type="text" name="TxtRut" placeholder="Rut" id="TxtRut" class="input-48">
            <input type="number" name="Telefono" placeholder="Teléfono de contacto" id="Telefono" class="input-dif">
            <label for="">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
            <input type="date" name="FechaNaci" placeholder="Año de nacimiento" id="FechaNaci" class="input-dif2">
            <select name="" id=""></select>
            <select id="regiones"></select>
            <select id="comunas" ></select>
            <input type="button" value="Registrar!" name="BtnRegistro" id="BtnRegistro" class="Boton">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi código CSS de mi proyecto:

```
    *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url("/Imagenes/Ahorasi.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

h1{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

select {
    width: 48%;
    height: 52px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.Registro{
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgba(63, 59, 59, 0.733);
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.FormTitulo {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.171);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}

.FormSubtitulo {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}

.Contenedor-Registro{
    padding: 10px 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

input{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.input-48{
    width: 48%;
}

.input-100{
    width: 100%;
}

.input-dif{
    margin-left: 4%;
    width: 48%;
}

.input-dif2{
    margin-left: 52%;
    width: 48%;
}

.Boton {
    border: none;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.212);
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.Boton {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.493); 
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    border: 2px solid rgb(119, 121, 119);
}

.Boton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.226);
    color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
}
```

Imagen de cómo se ve la página

[image: No logro colocar los select de forma correcta dentro de mi formulario, siguiendo con el mismo diseño del resto de la página. eh probado con br con padding todo]

Comment: No te parece usar bootstrap?

Comment: La verdad no tengo conocimiento de bootstrap, estoy recién comenzando en el desarrollo web @PauloUrbanoRivera

Comment: Bootstrap es una librería que te facilita de forma extraordinaria el diseño de un sistema o página web, ya que tiene clases predefinidas que te sirven para ello. Te recomiendo enormemente que lo comiences a utilizar colega

Comment: Si es para algo sencillo, puedes usar una librería ligera, minimalista. Hay varias muy buenas. Te recomiendo [`bulma`](https://bulma.io). Bootstrap es una buena librería, pero en diseños simples es como usar un camión para transportar un hoja de papel. Bulma usa solamente [este archivo](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css), que pesa muy poco. Lo incluyes al principio de tu HTML y listo. Está explicado en su documentación.

Comment: Alguna forma para poder solucionar el problema con mi diseño ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

esto es mas o menos lo que debes hacer, utiliza div para agrupar estilos y anchos:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url("/Imagenes/Ahorasi.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

h1{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

select {
    width: 48%;
    height: 52px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.Registro{
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgba(63, 59, 59, 0.733);
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.FormTitulo {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.171);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}

.FormSubtitulo {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}

.Contenedor-Registro{
    padding: 10px 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

input{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.input-48{
    width: 48%;
}

.input-100{
    width: 100%;
}

.input-dif{
    margin-left: 4%;
    width: 48%;
}

.div-dif{
  width: 100%; 
  display:table;
}

.div-dif2{
  width: 50%; 
  float:left;
}

select {
  width:200px;
}

.Boton {
    border: none;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.212);
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.Boton {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.493); 
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    border: 2px solid rgb(119, 121, 119);
}

.Boton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.226);
    color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Imagenes/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/Regiones.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Registro - Adopción</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="FormTitulo">Registro de Adopción</h1>
    <form action="" class="Registro">
        <h2 class="FormSubtitulo">CREA UNA NUEVA CUENTA</h2>
        <div class="Contenedor-Registro">
            <input type="email" name="TxtCorreo" placeholder="Correo Electronico" id="TxtCorreo" class="input-100">
            <input type="text" name="TxtNombres" placeholder="Nombre Completo" id="TxtNombres" class="input-100">
            <input type="text" name="TxtRut" placeholder="Rut" id="TxtRut" class="input-48">
            <input type="number" name="Telefono" placeholder="Teléfono de contacto" id="Telefono" class="input-dif">
            <div class="div-dif" >
            <div class="div-dif2" >
              <label for="FechaNaci" >Fecha de nacimiento</label>
              <input type="date" name="FechaNaci" placeholder="Año de nacimiento" id="FechaNaci"   />
             </div>
            <div class="div-dif2" style="margin-top:20px;">
               <select name=""></select>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-dif" >
            <div class="div-dif2" >
            <select id="regiones"  ></select>
            </div>
            <div class="div-dif2">
            <select id="comunas" ></select>
            </div>
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Registrar!" name="BtnRegistro" id="BtnRegistro" class="Boton">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```